# Passing a DOM element as event.target in jest is interpreted as an empty object

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I use jest, enzyme to test my React component (Summary). In this component I have a button with an onClick function that manipulates DOM node relative to this button. The function works as expected in browser, but when I test it (I simulate a 'click' on the button and pass the event.target as the button itself) - my Component says that event.target is an empty object.

Summary's function

```
showOrderList(event) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(event)) //logs {"target":{}}
        const $this = event.target;
        const list = $this.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('orderItems')[0];
        list.classList.toggle('hidden');
    };
```

the test

```
it('button "Elementy" invokes style-changing showOrderList() onClick', (done) => {
        configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

        const showOrderList = jest.spyOn(Summary.prototype, 'showOrderList');

        const name = 'Kuba';
        const age = '666';
        const created = '123'
        const list = [{name: name, age: age, created: created,
            items: [{id: 0, color: 'blue', size: 's'}]}];

        const component = shallow(
            <Summary />
        );

        component.instance().setState({
            list: list
        });
        component.update();

        setTimeout(function () {
            const showElemsBtn = component.find('.showElems').at(0);
            const mockshowElemsBtnEvent = { target: showElemsBtn};

            showElemsBtn.simulate('click', mockshowElemsBtnEvent);

            setTimeout(function () {
                expect(showOrderList).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockshowElemsBtnEvent);

                done();
                component.unmount();
            }, 500);
        }, 4000)
    });
```